# How is php representing floats

Tags: php

```
php > $a = 0.1;
php > $b = 0.2;
php > echo $a + $b;
0.3
```

I would expect the output to be `0.30000000000000004` however the output is `0.3`

Of course:

```
var_dump($a + $b == 0.3);
php shell code:1:
bool(false)
```

How is php deciding to represent the float numbers?

Comment: Your `php.ini` `precision` may play a role here.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision Default is 14

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski PHP 7 also appears to change things a bit. https://3v4l.org/um3Oa

Comment: Is it possible to configure it to be like in other languages? That is choosing minimal representation without collisions?

Comment: I don't know what "minimal representation without collisions" means. You can pick a precision value that works for you, you can `round()`, or you can use a math package that handles floating point better (especially if you're working with something where it's important, like someone's bank balances).

Comment: @ceejayoz As far as I know (but I don't have a solid reference for this) python, js or java give a string representation that is injective and minimal in the number of digits. 0.1 + 0.2 is not printed as 0.3 because there is a floating number that is closer to that value. That number is printed as 0.3, although it is obviously not exactly 0.3.

Comment: The literal answer to your title is, I believe, this C function: https://heap.space/xref/php-src/Zend/zend_strtod.c?r=589bdf30#3679 I've no idea how this compares to the algorithms used in other languages.